# Tomcat application Web.xml custom filter giving error of resource has moved; filter redirects https to http

Tags: http, tomcat, https, servlet-filters, web.xml

FYI: I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2, with IIS 7.5 and Apache Tomcat 5.5.  IIS talks to Tomcat, via the AJP Connector, version 1.3.  Tomcat is SSL enabled; so, the web site is enabled for both HTTP and HTTPS traffic.  I also have a security constraint in the web.xml file to redirect to enforce HTTPS traffic for a particular file, via the url-pattern.

Having said all that, I have created a servlet filter that is supposed to redirect https to http.  Unfortunately, when I restart the tomcat server and type in the login page, I get the following error:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I created the class in Eclipse and exported it as a JAR file called RedirectToHTTP.jar, and I placed this file in the WEB-INF/lib directgory of the application, NOT in the Tomcat installation directory.

I don't know what the problem is and I would appreciate any feedback.  Thank you.

**Update**

Upon recommendation in the comments, I checked the log files found an error related to my filter

> -- Exception starting filter redirectFilter
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: myfilterpkg/RedirectToHTTPFilter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0.

I compiled the filter with JRE 1.7.  I think Tomcat might be using a lower version of JRE.  Could that be the problem?

Here is the relevant data in the web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UTF8Encoder</filter-name>
     <filter-class>com.remedy.arsys.support.UTF8EncodingFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>Param1</param-name>
         <param-value>0</param-value>
     </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>redirectFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>myfilterpkg.RedirectToHTTPFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UTF8Encoder</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>*.jsp</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>redirectFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is the Java class:

```
package myfilterpkg;

import java.io.IOException;  

import javax.servlet.Filter;  
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;  
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession; 

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class RedirectToHTTPFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if ((request instanceof HttpServletRequest) && (response instanceof HttpServletResponse)) {
            String redirectTarget = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString().replaceFirst("https", "http");

            if(request.isSecure()) {
                ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect(redirectTarget);
            }
            else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

Comment: The filter-mapping for UTF8Encoder seems to be wrong, it defines a `servlet-name` instead of a `url-mapping`. Could that  have something to do with it? EDIT: It's indeed inside the official deployment descriptor spec, although I've never seen it before.

Comment: That was written by someone else and is a third-party closed-source filter.  I never had problems with the application, until I wrote the redirect filter and applied it.  I can try commenting out the utf8 filter, for now, and see if it changes the outcome.  I commented it out and I still get the same error.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Does the tomcat logfile say something interesting? You might want to take a look at `<tomcat-home>/logs/catalina.out`.

Comment: I think mine is called stdout.log, but I did find an an error in the log stating: "- Exception starting filter redirectFilter java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: myfilterpkg/RedirectToHTTPFilter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0.  I compiled it with JRE 1.7.  I think Tomcat might be using a lower versson of JRE.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: Definitely! Compile the filter with the source level of the runtime your tomcat actually runs in.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, now it's at least recognizing and executing the filter.  It definitely was the the version of the JRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter must be compiled with the source level of the runtime the tomcat server actually runs in. Otherwise you will get above error when classloading.